# Why does PHP replace some values queried from Oracle with zeros and nulls?

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I have a query in a PHP file which is sent to the Oracle DB using 'oci8'.

The problem is when I get the result back, most of the values I see normally when executing the query in SQL developer, are replaced with `0` or `null` values in PHP.

I tried using `oci_set_prefetch($parseQuery, 100000000);` just to be sure but that did not do the trick.

I even created a view in the DB and queried from that but still the same problem.

Any ideas?

**php code**:

```
<?php
  include("db_connection.php");   

  $query = "SQL query...";    

  $parseQuery = oci_parse($connection, $query);

  oci_execute($parseQuery);
  oci_set_prefetch($parseQuery, 100000000);
  $sqlResultJson = array();    

  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($parseQuery, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    array_push($sqlResultJson, $row);
  }

  $json = json_encode($sqlResultJson);

  echo $json;    
?>
```

**result is**:

```
[{
    "NIMETUS": "Lepingu maht",
    "A2013": "145333",
    "JAANUAR": "16095",
    "VEEBRUAR": "16095",
    "MARTS": "16095",
    "APRILL": "16095",
    "MAI": "16095",
    "JUUNI": "16095",
    "JUULI": "16095",
    "AUGUST": "16095",
    "SEPTEMBER": "16095",
    "OKTOOBER": "16095",
    "DETSEMBER": "16095",
    "KOKKU_2014": "193138",
    "KOKKU": "338471"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Planeeritud",
    "A2013": "154531",
    "JAANUAR": null,
    "VEEBRUAR": null,
    "MARTS": null,
    "APRILL": null,
    "MAI": null,
    "JUUNI": null,
    "JUULI": null,
    "AUGUST": "14801",
    "SEPTEMBER": "17304",
    "OKTOOBER": null,
    "DETSEMBER": null,
    "KOKKU_2014": "199594",
    "KOKKU": "354125"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Tegelik",
    "A2013": "161533",
    "JAANUAR": "17505",
    "VEEBRUAR": "17294",
    "MARTS": "876",
    "APRILL": "0",
    "MAI": "0",
    "JUUNI": "0",
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "35675",
    "KOKKU": "197208"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Aeguvad kokku lepitud",
    "A2013": "0",
    "JAANUAR": null,
    "VEEBRUAR": null,
    "MARTS": null,
    "APRILL": null,
    "MAI": null,
    "JUUNI": null,
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "0",
    "KOKKU": "39765"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Aeguvad paigaldamata",
    "A2013": "0",
    "JAANUAR": null,
    "VEEBRUAR": null,
    "MARTS": null,
    "APRILL": null,
    "MAI": null,
    "JUUNI": null,
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "0",
    "KOKKU": "14360"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Aeguvad jooksvalt planeerimata",
    "A2013": "0",
    "JAANUAR": null,
    "VEEBRUAR": null,
    "MARTS": null,
    "APRILL": null,
    "MAI": null,
    "JUUNI": null,
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "0",
    "KOKKU": "8811"
  }]
```

**but it should be (i got that by creating a new table in base with the result of the actual query)**:

```
 [{
    "NIMETUS": "Lepingu maht",
    "A2013": "145333",
    "JAANUAR": "16095",
    "VEEBRUAR": "16095",
    "MARTS": "16095",
    "APRILL": "16095",
    "MAI": "16095",
    "JUUNI": "16095",
    "JUULI": "16095",
    "AUGUST": "16095",
    "SEPTEMBER": "16095",
    "OKTOOBER": "16095",
    "DETSEMBER": "16095",
    "KOKKU_2014": "193138",
    "KOKKU": "338471"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Planeeritud",
    "A2013": "154531",
    "JAANUAR": "23399",
    "VEEBRUAR": "17194",
    "MARTS": "15539",
    "APRILL": "17013",
    "MAI": "17276",
    "JUUNI": "15941",
    "JUULI": "13638",
    "AUGUST": "14801",
    "SEPTEMBER": "17304",
    "OKTOOBER": "17337",
    "DETSEMBER": "13226",
    "KOKKU_2014": "199594",
    "KOKKU": "354125"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Tegelik",
    "A2013": "161533",
    "JAANUAR": "17505",
    "VEEBRUAR": "17294",
    "MARTS": "876",
    "APRILL": "0",
    "MAI": "0",
    "JUUNI": "0",
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "35675",
    "KOKKU": "197208"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Aeguvad kokku lepitud",
    "A2013": "0",
    "JAANUAR": "10431",
    "VEEBRUAR": "9584",
    "MARTS": "9817",
    "APRILL": "2655",
    "MAI": "2594",
    "JUUNI": "4684",
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "0",
    "KOKKU": "39765"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Aeguvad paigaldamata",
    "A2013": "0",
    "JAANUAR": "468",
    "VEEBRUAR": "889",
    "MARTS": "3886",
    "APRILL": "2264",
    "MAI": "2477",
    "JUUNI": "4376",
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "0",
    "KOKKU": "14360"
  },
  {
    "NIMETUS": "Aeguvad jooksvalt planeerimata",
    "A2013": "0",
    "JAANUAR": "0",
    "VEEBRUAR": "5",
    "MARTS": "1032",
    "APRILL": "1159",
    "MAI": "2386",
    "JUUNI": "4229",
    "JUULI": "0",
    "AUGUST": "0",
    "SEPTEMBER": "0",
    "OKTOOBER": "0",
    "DETSEMBER": "0",
    "KOKKU_2014": "0",
    "KOKKU": "8811"
  }]
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data (especially rows containing the *strange* data) and the code used to fetch it?

Comment: Is it the same without `json_encode`?

Comment: no still the same... just tried imploding a certain object from the array:
$string = implode(",", $sqlResultJson[1]);
 
echo $string;

Comment: **without** the `json_encode`

Comment: yes I understood. after while loop i wrote:$string = implode(",", $sqlResultJson[1]); echo $string; and still got NULL values

Comment: Ah I missread.. sorry! Rreally strange output.. can't help further sry :/

Comment: i tried oci_fetch_row as well. same problem. even wrapped my sql output fields to > to_number() just in case but nothing. I suspect there's something happening with the OCI module itself or database is rejecting a part of the query somewhy... although it works fine in sqlDeveloper... i don't know :(